# lldb - how to print an object without summary?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, lldb

Problem: I've created a summary for my object, let's think a trivial boost::intrusive_ptr (I have more complex, so this is just for example )

now if I have:

```
boost::intrusive_ptr< MyClass >  pobj;
```

and I type from the console

```
p pobj
```

I'll see summary for MyClass.

But what if I want to see it's internal px member - that is pobj.px ?

I know two ways:

- put summary into a category, then temporary disable it (inconvenient)
- frame variable -Y0
  and this second would be ideal, but what to do if I want to see a result of an expression ?
  that is something like p MyObj.GetContents.GetSmartPtr()

I've tried already something like:

```
frame variable -Y0 $0
```

but this doesn't work.

I use XCode 4.6.3.

Is there a way to turn off summary ?
Probably someone knows if this was cured in XCode 5 or latest lldb ?

Answer (score 3):

You can see the raw information by using `frame variable -R`.

```
(lldb) fr v test
(std::__1::string) test = "hi there"

(lldb) fr v -R test
(std::__1::string) test = {
  __r_ = {
    std::__1::__libcpp_compressed_pair_imp<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__rep, std::__1::allocator<char> > = {
      __first_ = {
         = {
[...]
```

**update**: OP clarifies that he's at a value in a convenience variable, e.g.
    std::string foo () { return std::string("hi there"); }

```
(lldb) p foo()
(std::string) $0 = "hi there"
```

and wants to view `$0` without any formatting -- and `frame variable` doesn't have access to the convenience variables so this needs to go through the `expression` (aka `p`) command.  In this case, the only workaround I know is to temporarily disable the format e.g. `type category disable libcxx` which is what this person is hoping to avoid doing.

Comment: this doesn't help against expressions. that is if there is no 'test' but std::string is just returned as a result of a function.

Comment: The Top-of-Tree open source LLDB has a -R (—raw-output) flag